# Strapi | How to connect in database using async credentials?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, asynchronous, strapi, aws-secrets-manager

I’m need get database credentials from Amazon Aws Secrets in a async call, but the database.ts file is syncronous so an error occur when Strapi try to connect in database:

```
Error: Unknown dialect undefined
```

So my question is: How to connect in database with async credentials?